# npm script section "clean:dist" vs "clean"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to figure out the role of "clean:dist" or "clean:js" vs "clean" inside package.json scripts section? I've searched the web and looked at [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) but couldn't find any clue. So can someone please help by explaining the role as well as the use of "clean:dist" or "clean:js" vs "clean"? Thanks

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean:dist"   : "rimraf dist",
    "clean:js"     : "rimraf public/js/main*.js && rimraf public/js/app.js && rimraf public/js/plugins.js && rimraf public/js/*.map",
    "clean:css"    : "rimraf public/css/main*.css && rimraf public/css/app*.css && rimraf public/css/*.map",
    "clean:fonts"  : "rimraf public/fonts/*",
    "clean:server" : "rimraf server.js && rimraf server.js.map",
    "clean:tmp"    : "rimraf tmp",
    "clean"        : "run-s clean:dist clean:tmp clean:server clean:css clean:js clean:fonts",
    "update:schema": "babel-node tools/update-schema.js",
    "admin-check"  : "cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-node tools/check-admin-user.js",
    "hot:server"   : "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --colors --display-    "start": "node server.js"
}
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can you please elaborate or if possible please provide link to any documentation explaining arbitrary tasks and their usage in package.json scripts section? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can specify any task you want in the `package.json` file.

Here the `clean:dist` task calls `rimraf` which a quick google search got me [here](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) (it's a shorthand for `rm -rf`);

The `clean:js` task deletes files from the `public` dir.

The `clean` task seems to be using [this](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) library to run multiple clean tasks at once.

For more information on `npm` scripts/tasks, just go [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)